# How to turn parameterized anonymous class into lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to refactor my code (Sonar also wants me to do that :) ).

I should use a lambda instead of an anonymous class.

I have the following code:

```
@Component
public class InsuranceValidateRespDataToDtoMapper extends PropertyMapConfigurerSupport<InsuranceValidateResponseData,
        com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData> {

    @Override
    public PropertyMap<InsuranceValidateResponseData, com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData> mapping() {
        return new PropertyMap<InsuranceValidateResponseData, com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackCurr()).setLackCurr(null);
                using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackEur()).setLackEur(null);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I make the following change, the code won't compile.

```
@Component
public class InsuranceValidateRespDataToDtoMapper extends PropertyMapConfigurerSupport<InsuranceValidateResponseData,
        com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData> {

    @Override
    public PropertyMap<InsuranceValidateResponseData, com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData> mapping() {
        return () -> {
            using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackCurr()).setLackCurr(null);
            using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackEur()).setLackEur(null);
        };
    }
}
```

Compilation fails because it can't resolve "using" and "source"

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: I imagine the error is that return cannot be used directly inside a class block...

Comment: it would be nice if you posted the compilation error..

Comment: Try replacing your whole method body with `return () -> {using(...)}` without `return new PropertyMap..`

Comment: You should add your definition of `PropertyMap` to your question. If `PropertyMap` is a functional *interface* and `source` a variable within it, it must be a constant, but doesn’t follow the naming conventions for constants. That’s not helpful here. But generally, the answer is, lambda expressions do not inherit members of the functional interface to which you eventually assign them. For `static` members, you can use qualified names or `import static` to resolve them, for non-`static` members (i.e. `default` methods), you are out of luck. Doesn’t work with lambdas.

Comment: PropertyMap is not a functional interface. Here is the link to the sources https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
return new PropertyMap<InsuranceValidateResponseData, com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData>() {
return () -> {
        using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackCurr()).setLackCurr(null);
        using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackEur()).setLackEur(null);
    };
}
```

There are **two** returns in there - doesn't make sense; go for that second

```
return -> { ... }
```

only; and remove the other stuff that you have in front of it!

But the **more** important aspect here: don't do things *blindly* because some tool **tells** you so.

Instead: step back; **understand** what the tool is telling you (like: what are the options; and do you really buy into "that other option is better than what you have right now"). Sure, if everybody agrees on "we want 0 SonarQube warnings", then that is what you could do. On the other hand; when touching code; as said: don't do it blindly. Maybe you can step back; and even do a **better** refactoring here.

(I am not saying that this is possible here; I am just pointing out: when you are touching your code; make sure that the change you will commit makes really sense to you).

Comment: I had tipfeler and have just edited. Sorry. Also, I do not do things blindly. I am only interested in lambdas.

Comment: That remark about blindly doing things wasn't a specific reaction to you personally, I meant that as more general remark for future readers. Just wondering, the answer itself works?

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting your method like this, if your `PropertyMap` is functional interface

```
@Override
public PropertyMap<InsuranceValidateResponseData, com.package.InsuranceValidateResponseData> mapping() {
    return () -> {
        using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackCurr()).setLackCurr(null);
        using(BIG_DECIMAL_TO_INTEGER_AMOUNT_CONVERTER).map(source.getLackEur()).setLackEur(null);
    };
}
```

Functional interfaces can be represented like lambda-functions, and in this case you only need to write a lambda-function for that single method from functional interface. Simple example with [BiConsumer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html):

```
BiConsumer<String, String> getConsumer() {
    return new BiConsumer<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s, String s2) {
            // accept strings
        }
    };
}
```

Can be represented as lambda-function with specifying only `accept` method:

```
BiConsumer<String, String> getConsumer() {
    return (s, s2) -> {
        // accept strings
    };
}
```